# Witholding Tax Payment

Tags: united-states, taxes, broker

I am involved in trade that is coming to a close, yet the broker has requested for me to pay 5% for the withholding tax, which will be refunded later. Is this normal practice?

note: Broker in Indonesia, and trading in the US

Comment: Pay *him* the 5%?

Comment: Yes, pay them the 5% and then it will be refunded, seems rather daft or!?!

Comment: Where is this? Provide a country tag. What exactly is this trade? They may be asking for commission not tax. You haven't provided enough information to ask if it is normal or not.

Comment: @J.Smith seems pretty daft to me, since -- at least in the US -- withholding **tax** goes directly to the Treasury Dept.

Comment: Is it put into escrow, and not cashed ?

Comment: Broker in Indonesia, and trading in the US.